# How to print 'State' values in react js in pattern given below using map?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

```
 <tbody>
  {nums.map(index => {
           return (
                <tr >
                     <td>A</td>
                           {reservedSeat.map((obj, index) => {
                                   return (
                                                <>
                                                    <td><Button >{obj.seatno}</Button></td>
                                                </>
                                            )
                           })}
                    </tr>
                     )
        })}
 </tbody>
```

Here the reservedSeat is array of objects. Each object contains id and name

output i got :
A001 A002 A003 A004 A005 B001 B002 B003 B004 B005 C001 C002 C003 C004 C005 \n
A001 A002 A003 A004 A005 B001 B002 B003 B004 B005 C001 C002 C003 C004 C005 \n
A001 A002 A003 A004 A005 B001 B002 B003 B004 B005 C001 C002 C003 C004 C005

pattern:

```
A001 A002 A003 A004 A005 \n
B001 B002 B003 B004 B005 \n
C001 C002 C003 C004 C005 \n
```

Comment: Add code to show what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it via [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to let every 5 element in oneline and then output it in `react`

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const state=["A001","A002","A003","A004","A005","B001","B002","B003","B004","B005","C001","C002","C003","C004","C005"]
    
    let data = []
    for(let i=0;i<state.length;i=i+5){
     data.push(state.slice(i,i+5).join(" ")) 
    }

    return (
      <table border='1'>
       {
         data.map(d => {
           return <tr><td>{d}</td></tr>
         })
       }
      </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry bro i didnt menion that state is array of objects. it includes id field and name field. Output is not correct because of that.

Comment: @nihal muhammed So why dont' you modify your question, with the correct state data, so others can understand your question?

Comment: Question modified and your solution helped thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach.  We can first join the entire array together on a single space.  Then do a global regex search on the following pattern:

```
\w+(?: \w+){4}
```

This will return an array of all row matches, which we can then join into a single string on newline.

```js
state = ["A001","A002","A003","A004","A005","B001","B002","B003","B004","B005","C001","C002","C003","C004","C005"];
var output = state.join(" ").match(/\w+(?: \w+){4}/g).join(" \n");
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Seems OP want to show them via react

Comment: @lucumt React is a JS framework...the underlying language is still JavaScript.